# I am getting error in chrome extension about sendmessage undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am making chrome extension but I am getting error of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')"
My content.js file is

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", event => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ mycontent: "from content script" })
    console.log("tab is active")
  } else {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ mycontent: "from content script" })
    console.log("tab is inactive")
  }
})
```

And my background.js file is

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.mycontent) {

  }
})
```

and my manifest.json file is

```
{
  "name": "Ju Close Chrome",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },

  "permissions": ["notifications", "storage", "alarms", "activeTab"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```